# Reset values in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have created an app with an activity where the user chooses items from a list and checkbox them and then clicks End.

When he clicks End he returns to a previous activity where I read in it which items he chose from the list by using `onActivityResult`.

My problem is that if for example the user Choose `Item1` + `Item2` and then in the 2nd time he chooses `Item3` **only**, it will show me like he chose `Item1`+`Item2`+`Item3`.

For some reason, it keeps `Item1`+`Item2` even that it was in the previous activation.

How can I clear them?

I tried this (`setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`):

```
Intent confirmedData = new Intent();
confirmedData.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
confirmedData.putExtra( "confirmedItems", (Serializable) itemsSelected );
confirmedData.putExtra( "dateInMillis",DateInMillis );
setResult(ChatActivity.RESULT_OK,confirmedData);

finish();
```

My `OnActivityResult` is:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_OK){

            confirmedItems = (ArrayList<Items>)data.getSerializableExtra("confirmedItems");
            DateInMillis = data.getLongExtra( "dateInMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());

        }
        if (resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello bro, you'll have to share code which you are using Intent of startActivityForResult(). Do one more thing place breakpoint on setResult(ChatActivity.RESULT_OK,confirmedData); this line and check how many items are being returned. Then I'll tell your where exactly issue is.

Comment: I debug it and it seems like when I debug everything works well and when it's in realtime then a problem occurs. I'm wondering if it is due to the speed of calculations. Maybe it adds items before it deletes the previous?

Comment: So your problem is duplicated data for "confirmedItems"? What about "dateInMillis"?

Comment: In onActivityResult() method you have a resultCode check, first clear your confirmedItems then add new items what you are returning back from 2nd Activity.
Try this!

Comment: Can you please write what you mean?